# Java socket connection - how to set a timeout when connecting server restarts

Tags: java, sockets, java-7

I have a Java socket connection established with a server A. Server A randomly restarts during the day and my Java socket connection infinitely waits because it thinks that is receiving data.
I have set the soTimeout but it is only kicking in while read is still going on.
How do I set force a timeout on the socket connection? I want to break the socket connection after a set period of time.

```
Socket mySocket = new Socket(host, port) ;
mySocket.setKeepAlive(true);
mySocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
```

Comment: Try using a Timer thread then close the socket when done

Comment: You can't know about the other side of the connection unless you try to read/write from the server socket. I would try to check read something, manage the exception and close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to break the connection periodically. You may just use TCP Keepalive mechanism to send small "ping" requests in defined intervals. Whenever one of parties does not respond, TCP connection is closed. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive